# Why does observable fire twice in Angular5?

Tags: angular, firebase

I'm using angular5 and angular firebase2.
I have a simple question.
I'm trying to make keyword comparing module now.
Everything is fine, and actually, but observable is firing twice.
I have no clue why it's firing exactly twice.

Here's my code.

```js
/*add-store.component.ts*/
 
  serverCheckKeyword(value) {
    this.test = this.storeService.checkCategory();
    this.test.subscribe(
      data => {
        if (data) {
          // Here, firing twice
          // some categories in Server
          this.objToArr(data);
        } else { // no categories in server
          console.log('No data in server');
          this.nothingData(value);
        }
      });
  }
    
  objToArr(data) {
  //...
  // I think I'm using this wrong. This part was the problem what I've figured out.
    this.storeService.addCategory(this.sortKeyword[keywordIdx], size+1);
  }
```

```js
/*store.service.ts*/

  addCategory(data, id) {
    const path = `category/${data.name}`;
    const item = {
      id: id,
      categoryName: data.name
    };

    this.db.object(path).update(item)
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  // Load all of Categories
  checkCategory() {
    return this.db.list('category').valueChanges();
  }
```

Comment: Do you call `serverCheckKeyword` method multiple times?

Comment: See this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/67853802/5466477

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because you went on another routed component, and you forgot to unsubscribe from the subscription.

Add a reference to your subscription

```
this['http_call'] = this.test.subscribe(...);
```

And delete it on destroy

```
ngOnDestroy() { this['http_call'].unsubscribe(); }
```

Otherwise, this can come from the fact that Firebase listens to databse events. This means that if you made a change to your base, your observer will be notified.

You can prevent that by "cancelling" the database listener with this

```
return this.db.list('category').valueChanges()
  .pipe(take(1));
```

Comment: From my understanding, this is indeed because he updates a document in the category, thus refiring the whole process since the category collection is the source. A `.pipe(take(1))` after the update should prevent this to fire twice.

Comment: Or as I said, he destroyed the component and came back on it, and forgot to destroy the subscription. This is an issue that exists withtout Firebase, he should then cover both cases.

Comment: Sure, one should always unsubscribe to an observable if it has not complete, otherwise you expose your app to data leakage.

Comment: No, one should not always unsubscribe from an observable. **[This blog article](https://netbasal.com/when-to-unsubscribe-in-angular-d61c6b21bad3)** explains when and why, for instance.

Comment: Thus me saying "if it has not completed". We both agree. 
Thanks for the link, I am sure it will come helpful for others.

Comment: @trichetriche,Thanks for the reply. I tried both of way, but it's not worked.
still fire twice. In addtionally, second one I tried, make this error 'The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable<{}>'.'

Comment: Then make an MCVE for us to test, because I can't guess your error when I give you the correct answer. And as of your second issue, I didn't change your code, just added something, this should not trigger an error, you probably did something wrong on the side.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer to solve this issue. 
I just `this.test.unsubscribe()` after finishing logic.

```
serverCheckKeyword(value) {
this.test = this.storeService.checkCategory()
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      // some categories in Server
      if (data) {
        // Here was firing twice
        this.objToArr(data);
      } else { // no categories in server
        this.nothingData(value);
      }
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

}

...

```
this.storeService.addCategory(this.sortKeyword[keywordIdx], size + 1);
this.test.unsubscribe();
```

It works well!
Thank you all :)