# Disable caching in Angular Firestore queries

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I am running a firestore query to get data but the query is returning data from cached data queries earlier and then returns additional data (which was not queried earlier) in the second pass from server. Is there a way I can disable caching for firestore queries so that request goes to DB every time I query something.

```
this.parts$ = this.db.collection<OrderBom>('OrderBom', ref => {
      let query : firebase.firestore.Query = ref;
      query = query.where('orderPartLC', '==', this.searchValue.toLowerCase());
      return query;
    }).valueChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Change that `.valueChanges()` to a `.snapshotChanges()` then you can apply a filter. See the example below.**

I dont like changing default behavior (default configurations). **I saw it's a desired behavior and the good practice is to show the data as soon as possible to the user**, even if you refresh twice the screen.

I dont think is a bad practice to filter on `fromCache === false` when we dont have a choise. (In my case I do more requests after i receive this first one so due to promises and other async 'tasks' cache/server order is completly lost )

See [this closed issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2976)

```
  getChats(user : User) {
    return this.afs.collection<Chat>("chats", 
    ref => ref.where('participantsId', 'array-contains', user.id)
              .snapshotChanges()
              .pipe(filter(c=> c.payload.doc.metadata.fromCache === false)).
              .pipe(map(//probaly want to parse your object here))

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

if using AngularFire2 you can try:

1. I read on the Internet that you can disable offline persistence - which caches your results -by not calling enablePersistence() on AngularFireStoreModule.
2. I have done the first and still had no success, but try it first. What I managed to do to get rid of caching results was to use the get() method from class DocumentReference. This method receives as parameter a GetOptions, which you can force the data to come from server. Usage example:

```js
// fireStore is a instance of AngularFireStore injected by AngularFire2
    let collection = fireStore.collection<any>("my-collection-name");
    let options:GetOptions = {source:"server"}
    collection.ref.get(options).then(results=>{
    // results contains an array property called docs with collection's documents.
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Persistence and caching should be disabled for angular/fire by default but it is not and there is no way to turn it off. As such, @BorisD's answer is correct but he hasn't explained it too well. Here's a full example for converting `valueChanges` to `snapshotChanges`.

```
constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {}

private getSequences(collection: string): Observable<IPaddedSequence[]> {

  return this.afs.collection<IFirestoreVideo>('videos', ref => {
    return ref
      .where('flowPlayerProcessed', '==', true)
      .orderBy('sequence', 'asc')
  }).valueChanges().pipe(
    map((results: IFirestoreVideo[]) => results.map((result: IFirestoreVideo) => ({ videoId: result.id, sequence: result.sequence })))
  )
}
```

Converting the above to use `snapshotChanges` to filter out stuff from cache:

```
constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {}

private getSequences(collection: string): Observable<IPaddedSequence[]> {

  return this.afs.collection<IFirestoreVideo>('videos', ref => {
    return ref
      .where('flowPlayerProcessed', '==', true)
      .orderBy('sequence', 'asc')
  }).snapshotChanges().pipe(
    filter((actions: DocumentChangeAction<any>[], idx: number) => idx > 0 || actions.every(a => a.payload.doc.metadata.fromCache === false)),
    map((actions: DocumentChangeAction<any>[]) => actions.map(a => ({ id: a.payload.doc.id, ...a.payload.doc.data() }))),
    map((results: IFirestoreVideo[]) => results.map((result: IFirestoreVideo) => ({ videoId: result.id, sequence: result.sequence })))
  )
}
```

The only differences are that `valueChanges` changes to `snapshotChanges` and then add the `filter` DocumentChangeAction and `map` DocumentChangeAction lines at the top of the snapshotChanges pipe, everything else remains unchanged.

This approach is discussed [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2012#issuecomment-730035963)